# Symmetrical waveform of sound

Tags: sound

How can I record [my sound](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5emakmzf4xocw9u/tt5.wav?dl=0) to get the  symmetrical waveform?

```
AudioPlot[mysound, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Or

How can I transform "my sound" to get the   symmetrical waveform?

Comment: What is the 'symmetrical waveform'?

Comment: @N.J.Evans when the "axis of symmetry" is the horizontal blue line

Comment: This sounds like it is a question about recording equipment, not about Mathematica.  Also, the link to the sound file is broken.

Comment: It could be forced to symmetric with an appropriately chosen nonlinear transformation, but what is the point of doing such a thing?  This is an important question because there are infinitely many such transformations, most having an audible effect on the sound.

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to make  a 3D  gift from the sound wave. [see here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/02/12/spellbound-valentines-diy-art-from-3d-printed-sound/),  I want to rotate it around the horizontal axis.

Comment: But that question is completely unrelated to audio processing!  This is about graphics and 3D, and not about sound.  You don't have to make the *sound* symmetric.  Anyway, you don't need "symmetric" sound to use Vitaliy's method from that post.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in a visual representation of the audio waveform, there is no need to worry about the (audio) fidelity of the transformation. This reads in a sound, and then forces it to be symmetric.

```
a = Abs[AudioData[ExampleData[{"Audio", "BlackcapWarbler"}]][[1]]];
asym = Table[If[EvenQ[i], a[[i]], -a[[i]]], {i, Length[a]}];
ListLinePlot[asym, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see in your example ,audio file is `tt5.wav`.

```
audio = Audio["tt5.wav"];
minmax = AudioBlockMap[MinMax, audio, .01]
```

You can view the max, min and mean of audio.

```
Show[AudioPlot[audio, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> All], 
     ListLinePlot[minmax, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Darker[Green]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
     ListLinePlot[TimeSeriesMap[Mean, minmax], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Then Using sample of audio Subtract the mean of audio,then it should be a  symmetrical waveform.

you can use this to get it.Perfect!

```
newaudio = AudioSpectralMap[If[Abs@#Value < 2, 0., #Value] &, audio - Audio[TimeSeriesMap[Mean, minmax]]]

AudioPlot@newaudio
```

[image]